# How to add windows store-style interface to desktop app, similar to Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-8.1

I recently found a new feature of Google Chrome on windows 8.1: a "Windows 8 Mode" available from the menu in the top-right corner of the window: 
[image]

This opens a Windows Store-style interface, as if it were its own app: [image]

Does anyone know how Google does this, clearly without sideloading an app using the auto-generated "Add-AppDevPackage.ps1" powershell script that Visual Studio generates when you create an app package?

Thanks in advance,

MagikM18